# How to retrieve a value from a dictionary whose key is a variable set in group_vars in ansible

Tags: ansible, jinja2

(ansible 2.5) I am trying to retrieve a value from a dictionary called docker_facts, where environment is a variable set in the group_vars. I am unable to get this to work. I tried with double quotes and without the quotes. Does anyone have a way to get this to work ?

```
meta_state:  "{{ docker_facts['container_facts']['node']['/{{ environment }}/container1'] ['run_status']['inspect_status'] }}"
```

The error i am getting is:

```
 FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute '/{{ environment}}/container1'\n\nThe ....
```

#

Here is the snipped for the

```
 {
    "docker_facts": {
        "container_facts": {
            "node": {
                "/dev/container1": {
                    "address": "12.x.x.x"
                    "monitor_rule": {
                        "monitor_templates": []
                        "type": "Snapshot"
                    },
                    "monitor_status": "Applied",
                    "name": "dev-server
                    "run_status": {
                        "inspect_status": "pass",
                        "enabled_status": "running",
                    },
                       "session_status": "ENABLED"
                },
                "/prod/container1": {
                    "address": "12.1.0.2",
                   ........
                   ........
```

Here is the environments.yaml file located in group-vars as a hostgroup variable.

---

environment: dev

Comment: Can you share `docker_facts` and `environment` vars?

Comment: @imjoseangel I added the snippet for docker_facts to my original question above. I also added the variables yaml file. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Braces can't be nested. Once you have code inside braces, this code is interpreted as Jinja2 and you can use your variables anywhere.

To solve that, just use the variable environment without the quotes (with quotes it is a string, not a variable). In Jinja2, you can also concatenate a variable with other string as in Python:

```
meta_state:  "{{ docker_facts['container_facts']['node'][environment + '/container1'] ['run_status']['inspect_status'] }}"
```